How to reach the maximum bandwidth on many USB drives?
I have many (~60 at now) external USB drives which I need to occasionally, but regularly, connect to one Linux workstation because I need to run a sanity check program on data saved on them.
I don't need to connect all of them at the same time of course, but I would need to achieve the maximum number at maximum speed possible, to reduce the manual time I need to disconnect and connect other drives.
I bought a powered 16 port USB 3 hub and I'm using it, but if I connect too many drives at the same time (~ >10) I get occasional input/output errors and read-only forced mounted drives.
For this reason I'm wondering how I can obtain the maximum number of external drives at maximum speed:

using multiple additional USB 3.0 PCI-Express card
using multiple powered hub
other?

Do you have some hints?

There are many factors: https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/how-many-usb-devices-can-you-connect . PCIe cards are usually the best solution for an underpowered built-in usb host controller, but many hubs are built too cheaply to take advantage

Thanks @Cpt.Whale, so I understand that the best solution is 2 USB 3.0 PCI-Express card and 2 good 16 ports USB hubs. But how I can recognise a good USB hub?

You are getting into industrial types of USB hubs if you want to transfer data on 32 USB ports, but you can check spec sheets for advertised transfer rates and max power draw to fit your needs
